# MFSideMenu in UINavigationController not working when introduced with a modal Segue

Tags: menu, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to integrate MFSideMenu in my project but I don't want to adopt the approach described in the GitHub depository as it defines the menu in the app delegate.

I have a login screen which will introduce a navigation controller with the main page as reported in this picture[image]

I would like to add the support for MFSideMenu in the navigationcontroller root controller using this code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.sideMenuController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;

        MFSideMenuOptions options = MFSideMenuOptionMenuButtonEnabled|MFSideMenuOptionBackButtonEnabled
        |MFSideMenuOptionShadowEnabled;
        MFSideMenuPanMode panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeNavigationBar|MFSideMenuPanModeNavigationController;

        MFSideMenu *sideMenu = [MFSideMenu menuWithNavigationController:navigationController
                                                     sideMenuController:sideMenuController
                                                               location:MFSideMenuLocationLeft
                                                                options:options
                                                                panMode:panMode];

        sideMenuController.sideMenu = sideMenu;

    }
    return self;
}
```

When I run the app the menu button appears in my navigation bar and everything seems working fine but,if I introduce the navigation controller through a modal segue (i.e. a login screen which goes to the navigation controller in case of a correct login) the button disappears.

Any idea about how to fix it?